# Cross-browser way to keep long text to break but preserve words with vertically aligned image

Tags: css

Not sure if this question has been asked, but I don't want to cut any words in the middle unless the word is too long to fit in one line. I can normally do this with `word-wrap:break-word`, but in my case, I have a little image at the beginning of the text, which is vertically aligned and this makes it insert a line break if a word is too long to fit in one line.

http://jsfiddle.net/y2mps278/

How can I remove the line break? I tried using `white-space`, but I couldn't get anything. `word-break: break-all` works to remove the line break, but it cuts normal words in the middle. It's possible to alter the HTML structure for me if necessary.

I need this to work on IE11 and the latest version of Chrome and Firefox on Windows.

Comment: is this what you try to do ? http://jsfiddle.net/y2mps278/1/ cause then, span needs to be displayed as an inline **boxe**

Comment: Nope. The image needs to act exactly like normal text. So text would continue wrapping below the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that this isn't a content image...it's styling.

That being the case, we should push it to the CSS and use it as a background image

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 24px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-24-24-6.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center left;
  background-size: 24px 24;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <span>ThisIsAVeryLongSentenceWithNoSpacesDoesItRenderCorrectly?</span>

</div>

<div>
   
    <span>This On the Other Hand, is A Very Long Sentence With Spaces. Does It Render Correctly?</span>

</div>
```